# Start SQL Job from X++ Job in Axapta

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I want to trigger an SQL job which runs an SSIS package from an AX Job, I successfully ran SQL code fetching some records from an SQL table by creating a menu item for the job and have it run on the server instead of the client but the following code runs without errors but the Job's not started?

CODE:

```
    static void TriggerAllocation(Args _args)
{
    UserConnection userConnection;
    Statement statement;
str sqlStatement;
SqlSystem sqlSystem;
SqlStatementExecutePermission sqlPermission;
;

sqlSystem = new SqlSystem();

sqlStatement = "EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_start_job @Job_Name = 'MyJob'";

userConnection = new UserConnection();
statement = userConnection.createStatement();
sqlPermission = new SqlStatementExecutePermission(
sqlStatement);
sqlPermission.assert();

statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);

CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
```

I can't find any more clues in e.g. eventviewer, SQL logs as for what went wrong..

Kind regards,

Mike

[UPDATE] Thanks to Alex K I solved it!

using

```
statement.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
```

instead of

```
 statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
```

did the trick!

Keep in mind that running the job directly from AX won't work despite: *server* static void 
You'll have to create an Menu Item of type action with property RunOn=Server

[image: Menu Item]

Comment: go? maybe create a stored procedure an execute that?

Comment: Did you check windows event logs?  Using basically the same code, I get `Request for the permission of type 'SqlStatementExecutePermission' failed.` I'm not sure if you can use a UserConnection like this...perhaps type Connection instead?

Comment: Actually try `server static void Trigger...` and perhaps `statement.executeUpdate(...)` instead of `executeQuery`

Comment: When I said use `static server` I thought your code would eventually end up in a class, not a job :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have given my comment as an answer but wasn't paying attention:

Try `server static void Trigger...` and perhaps `statement.executeUpdate(...)` instead of `executeQuery`

Comment: Thnx Alex, executeUpdate was indeed the solution! At first I changed userconnection to connection like you said but after running it successfully I changed it back to userconnection and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Calling EXEC from `executeQuery` is not supported.

See this question:

[How to get the results of a direct SQL call to a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184152/how-to-get-the-results-of-a-direct-sql-call-to-a-stored-procedure)